# xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I'm having an issue with Fastlane and github-actions. I have a simple lane where I run tests, but scan can't see any simulators, which results in failure. I've tried many things, but nothing works. Changing Supported Platforms to iOS as recommended also doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea what to do?

[image]